# Using the new Buildsystem to build multiple 'Configurations' at once

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard, csproj

If I have a Project that builds against different target framework's I can specyfy `TargetFrameworks` instead of `TargetFramework` and MSBuild will build all frameworks on a single build without changing configurations.

I have a project that will be compiled against different frameworks (like WPF and Windows Forms) using some `#if`. I would like to define an array of values like `<usedFramework>Framework1;...;FrameworkN</usedFramework>` So one build will build all variations at the same time.

I tried to use `TargetFrameworks` with new names and then replacing the framework with the correct on later. But the VisualStudio did not like it.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>Framework1;Framework2</TargetFrameworks>
  <AssemblyName>PDFsharp</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Framework1'">
  <TargetFramework>net20</TargetFramework>
  <useedFramework>Framework1</usedFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Framework2">
  <TargetFramework>net20</TargetFramework>
  <useedFramework>Framework2</usedFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there another way then using the configuration / platform dropdowns from VisualStudio?

Comment: VS does not like many MSBuild hacks, not only the one you showed above. Thus, give it up and use two projects instead.

Comment: Is your goal to extend the experience inside VS or do you want to simplify build scripts? As Lex Li mentioned, the VS experience is hard to extend at this moment, but creating a target to build all configurations from command is fairly easy.

Comment: My goal is not a build script, but the expirience inside VS. Calling the compiler for multiple configurations from a script, that would be no problem. Using different projects, don't work as good, since the new Buildsystem no longer seems to support linked files. And I always found the shared project approach a bit confusing. If this does not work, I propably stick to configurations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shared projects and linked files should work. If you have issues with it ask another question or file an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible.

The only "multi-targeting" axis currently supported is multiple target frameworks. It is important that all the values in `TargetFrameworks` are parseable to known NuGet target framework monikers (TFMs) for some tooling to properly work.